# awk: equivalent of mysql's "\G" to print tabulated data in multiple lines

Tags: bash, mysql, awk

Is there an equivalent to mysql's "\G" at the end of the query but awk (or similar) that will to print tabulated data from a text file in multiple lines with the header next to it? Something that will do no matter how many columns are in the file. For example:

```
columnA    columnXYZ   columnBLAHBLAH
foo        bar        foobar
blah       blahblah   blahblahblah
[...]
```

Will turn into:

```
************ 1. row ***********
       columnA: foo
     columnXYZ: bar
columnBLAHBLAH: foobar
************ 2. row ***********
       columnA: blah
     columnXYZ: blahblah
columnBLAHBLAH: blahblahblah
[...]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

Content of `infile`:

```
columnA    columnXYZ   columnBLAHBLAH
foo        bar        foobar
blah       blahblah   blahblahblah
```

Content of `script.awk`:

```
FNR == 1 { 
    split( $0, header )
}

FNR > 1 { 
    printf "************ %d. row ************\n", FNR-1
    for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) { 
        printf "%14s: %-14s\n", header[ i ], $i
    }   
}
```

Run the script:

```
awk -f script.awk infile
```

And output:

```
************ 1. row ************
       columnA: foo           
     columnXYZ: bar           
columnBLAHBLAH: foobar        
************ 2. row ************
       columnA: blah                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
     columnXYZ: blahblah                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
columnBLAHBLAH: blahblahblah
```